# SPARQL query Pizza ontology

Tags: python, sparql, ontology

I am writing a sparql query so as to retrieve pizzas without a specific topping, for example here a pizza with no `CheeseTopping`. However, it is returning me pizzas with cheeses. I am using the Standford pizza ontology (https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl)

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>

SELECT ?pizza 
WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
        a owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
        owl:someValuesFrom ?topping                  
    ] . 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping .
    }
}
```

Comment: your current query does only check for pizzas where there is "any topping except CheeseTopping" - this clearly also holds for pizzas with multiple toppings including `CheeseTopping` as those pizzas would still match your query

Comment: what you have to filter for is the absence of the whole path: `SELECT distinct ?pizza 
WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
        a owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
        owl:someValuesFrom ?topping                  
    ] . 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
     ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
        owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
        owl:someValuesFrom ?topping2                  
    ] . 
        ?topping2 rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping .
    }
}`

Comment: if you don't care about any topping at all (i.e. the superclass `NamedPizza`, it becomes shorter: `SELECT distinct ?pizza 
WHERE {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
     ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
        owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
        owl:someValuesFrom ?topping                  
    ] . 
        ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping .
    }
}`

Comment: Note, it fails for the unnamed pizzas, because those do not have a simple `rdfs:subClassOf` relation to `Pizza` but a complex one, i.e. `X SubClassOf (Pizza and Y)` compared to `Z SubClassOf Pizza`

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank you so much. But an issue am running into is when it comes to SeafoodToppping subclass. if i put SeafoodTopping, it does not work as for the VegetableTopping or CheeseTopping. For the seafood part, i have to specify its subclasses, then it works.

Comment: ```PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>

SELECT ?pizza 
WHERE {
 ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza .
 ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [
  a owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; 
  owl:someValuesFrom ?topping                  
 ] . 
 ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:SeafoodTopping .
}``` this gives me no results whereas if i do

Comment: @UninformedUser whereas if i do ```PREFIX rdf: <w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX owl: <w3.org/2002/07/owl#> PREFIX rdfs: <w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX xsd: <w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> PREFIX pizza: <co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> SELECT ?pizza WHERE { ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:Pizza . ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf [ a owl:Restriction ; owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping; owl:someValuesFrom ?topping ] . ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:PrawnsTopping . } ``` this does work

Comment: that is a confusing thing in the ontology itself: what you see in Protege is by default the rendering of classes (and all other entities) by means of a label (`rdfs:label` annotation is used) - this in fact is supposed to provide a human readable form. The pitfall here is that the label is `SeafoodTopping` but for whatever reason the class URI is `pizza:FishTopping` - you can hower the class in Protege to see the full URI - or you can change the rendering: `View -> Render by entity IRI short ...`